# Convert PHP Array from One to Multi-dimensional Based on Parent ID Values

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I've got a one-dimensional array of objects that represent multi-dimensional data:

```
array(
    array(
        "id" => 1,
        "parent_id" => 0,
        "content" => 'des'
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 2,
        "parent_id" => 3,
        "content" => 'abc'
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 3,
        "parent_id" => 1,
        "content" => 'jjjj'
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 4,
        "parent_id" => 5,
        "content" => 'dsfsd'
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 5,
        "parent_id" => 0,
        "content" => 'dsfsd'
    )
);
```

How should I convert it into a multi-dimensional array?

```
array(
    array(
        "id" => 1,
        "parent_id" => 0,
        "content" => 'des'
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 3,
        "parent_id" => 1,
        "content" => 'jjjj'
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 2,
        "parent_id" => 3,
        "content" => 'abc'
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 5,
        "parent_id" => 0,
        "content" => 'dsfsd'
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 4,
        "parent_id" => 5,
        "content" => 'dsfsd'
    )
);
```

I'd like to sort by id and children after the parent, if parent_id = 0 it is the root element. Thanks everybody very much!

Comment: The first array you put has the "parent_id" order ` 0 3 1 5 0 `.  The second array's "parent_id" order is ` 0 1 3 0 5 `. Should it not be ` 0 0 1 3 5 `?  What is the login behind this?  And both your arrays are multi-dimensional, so the title does not make sense.  Explain it better.

Comment: i want sort by id and children after parent, if parent_id = 0 it is root element

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to sort the array by `parent_id`.

`array_sort()` a laravel helper function : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-array-sort

```
$sorted = array_sort($array, 'parent_id');
```

**output**

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "parent_id" => 0
    "content" => "des"
  ]
  4 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 5
    "parent_id" => 0
    "content" => "dsfsd"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "parent_id" => 1
    "content" => "jjjj"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "parent_id" => 3
    "content" => "abc"
  ]
  3 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "parent_id" => 5
    "content" => "dsfsd"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my code (done)

```
function sort($array){
    $newArray = [];
    sortLoop($array, $newArray);
    return $newArray;
}
function sortLoop($array, &$newArray, $parent_id = 0){
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if ($item['parent_id'] == $parent_id) {
            $newArray[] = $item;
            unset($array[$key]);
            sortLoop($array,$newArray, $item['id']);
        }
    }
}
```

Wish this useful for someone.